# Changing PHP request into fixed URL. (Wordpress Template Header)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Very short question but it seems like i'm just to dumb.

```
<div class="header-content" id="header-content">        
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
                <?php 
                    if(isset($theme_options['logo']) && isset($theme_options['logo']['url']) && $theme_options['logo']['url'] != ''){
                        echo '<img src="'.$theme_options['logo']['url'].'" alt="" />';
                    }
                    else{
                        echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/placeholder/logo.png" alt="" />';
                    }
                ?>

            </a>
        </div>
```

Since there is only just one "href" in it i thought i could change this line:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
```

Into:

```
<a href="http://example.com/" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
```

But after a cache clear and reload nothing changed. In case you didnt figured out what i try, its simple. I want to change the link the blog logo is leading to without changing the blog home url.

Comment: The change you made shouldn't have broken anything. Can you post your new code (including changes)?

Comment: It all looks good to me too, I bet it was still loading the cache (wp cache, not your browser). You could do a quick try `yourdomain.com/?` that will ignore the cache most of the time.

Comment: Thanks a lot sdcr. I didn't work on that website for months. Totally forgot about the external cache plugin that is running on it...